# Smooth scale SVG between two media queries

Tags: html

Is it possible to scale an SVG between two media queries, but not having the size jump from one scale to another, but doing it with a smooth transition?
For example between a min-width of 327px and a max-width of 388px, the SVG should be scaled from 50% to 100%. Is it possible doing this with media queries?

What I'm trying to do is match the resizing of an actaul  to that of an , which still has an SVG file as source. Although both SVG have the same size, viewport etc. both scale differently.

Comment: Have you tried scaling the parent element of the svg and not the svg itself?

Comment: I tried it with a parent element, but still can't figure out a way doing it right. I'll add some code to my question to explain it better